# Trying to install Eclipse w/ ADT plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm really not savvy with the minute details of whatever kinds of files so I'll try explaining my problem the best I can.

I'm trying to install Eclipse with the Android Development Tools plugin. I have a 64 bit windows 8 machine, and I downloaded both the JRE7 and Eclipse in 64 bit. When I try to start Eclipse, It says there no java virtual machine found at
C:\Users\XXXXX\Downloads\eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

I read something else about tweaking the eclipse.ini file but I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. Here's what my .ini file looks like. What should I do?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Why don't you just try [this eclipse/adt bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from developer.android.com. It has everything all in one. You shouldn't need to do a thing.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and I'm still having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install Java JDK and also **set path** in System Variables. Since the error specifically says that no Java virtual machine found, this could be the solution

Download it from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Don't forget to set path in System Variables and once done type javac in command prompt. If it is recognized try launching eclipse again. Maybe this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your installing plugins through Eclipse, it might help to run Eclipse as administrator and then try installing the plugin. Worked for me when i had problems installing plugins through Eclipse on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse.ini file make sure you are pointing -vm to your jdk installation.

EDIT: -vm needs to be the first entry in eclipse.ini file.